# Union DataTables C#

Tags: .net, ado.net, datatable

I have a list of datatables. What can be the most efficient way to club them in to single data table? The schema of each of these data tables is different and the row count of these tables may vary.

i.e.

- Table1 has columns A, B
- Table2 has columns C, D
- Table3 has columns E, F

My output should be a result-table with all above columns and should contain all the rows.

Is it achievable in a few lines of code? Could LINQ be an option?

Comment: I can do that in...three lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my above question:

```
                DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[1];

                DT.Columns.Add(primaryColumn, typeof(System.Int32));
                for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DT.Rows[i][primaryColumn] = i;
                }
                keys[0] = DT.Columns[primaryColumn];
                mapDT.PrimaryKey = keys;

                tables.Add(DT); 

    private static DataTable MergeDataTables(List<DataTable> tables, string keyColumn)
    {
        DataTable mergedTable = new DataTable();

        foreach (DataTable dt in tables)
            mergedTable.Merge(dt);

        mergedTable.PrimaryKey = null;

        mergedTable.Columns.Remove(keyColumn);

        return mergedTable;
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Used the `Merge` method. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx.

---

Update based on your comment. If you only have two columns in each table, then you cannot use the `Merge` method as you expect.

To do what you want, you will need a primary key on each table. When a row has a common identifer between the tables, the columns will be combined, instead of a row added. For instance, if RowId 1 is in both Table1 and Table 2, you will get RowId 1; A, B, C, D, Null, Null. If RowId 2 is in Table1 only then you get RowId2; A, B, Null, Null, Null, Null.

> *http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.missingschemaaction.aspx*
>
> user may explicitly set the primary key constraints on each DataTable.
>   This ensures that incoming records that match existing records are
>   updated instead of appended.

Comment: merge will increase the row count. I just want to add all those columns with data to single table.

Comment: Then I am not understanding what you want. Yes, obviously, it will increase the row count. It is important to have primary keys on these tables if you want to add column data for rows. For example, if I have a primary key set on Id for each table, then rows with the same id will have the column data added instead of a row added.

Comment: @buffer_overflow since they're all different and the column count can be different you have to add each table with a different command. There's no other way, since merge is not what you're after.

Comment: @buffer_overflow create a new table with the structure you want. Then,   you can use an `INSERT INTO newTable SELECT ... FROM FirstTable UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM SecondTable` and so on.

Comment: @AMissico If I add primary kesy to all data tables, I will end up getting distinct rows only.

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention in above approach is : if I have say 5 rows in each table, the result table will contain 15 rows. What I am looking for is a table with 5 rows but all the columns side by side.

Comment: @buffer_overflow; I would add your comment to the question.

Comment: @buffer_overflow; You could add an autonumber column to each table. Call the column "RowIndex". Set it as the primary key. (You may have to populate the value with the actual row index.) Do the merge, remove that column. It will give you exactly what you want.